# Upgrading from 8.3.7 to 8.4 conflicts with acquia/blt-project

Tags: 8, composer

In the composer.json file I added `"drupal/core": "~8.4"` to the *required* section. When I run `composer update drupal/core --with-all-dependencies`, I get the following output.

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - drupal/core 8.4.0 conflicts with acquia/blt-project

Why does Drupal 8.4 conflict with acquia/blt-project?

Comment: Read https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer#known-issues and update your question - or add an answer yourself ;-)

Comment: Why don't you simply `composer update --with-dependencies`? I do that every now and then at least once a week and never had any problem.

Comment: I’ve been googling this conflict for a day now but haven’t found a solution.  This conflict is more about acquia/blt issue I think.  Yep done that command also without any luck.

Comment: Is there an update to the module that can be run first to avoid the conflict?

Comment: Good point @LittleCoding I'm currently using the latest version of acquia/blt  "8.9.3"

Comment: Looks like the 8.9.x version is in EOL and only has support for <= D8.5.. look at the 8.8.x or 9.x version for support of D8.4. Have a look at the 9.x README.md https://github.com/acquia/blt/blob/9.x/docs/README.md

Comment: thanks @LittleCoding - I'm now talking to Acquia to help with this conflict.  I will post back any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a line in my composer.json file which is prevent the upgrade from happening.

In the "conflict" section, there's a line `"drupal/core": ">=8.4.0-alpha1"`
I have to remove that line and also run the following commands to complete the upgrade.

```
composer update --lock
composer require acquia/lightning:^3.0 acquia/blt:^8.9 --no-update
composer update acquia/lightning --with-all-dependencies
```